# Drop-down menu that opens up/upward with pure css

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I've created a dropdown menu with pure CSS and I've gotten it to a place that I like except I want it to be "drop-up" not "drop-down" since the menu bar is going at the bottom of the layout. What I need to add or change to make it "drop-up"?

```css
#menu * { 
  padding:0; 
  margin: 0; 
  font: 12px georgia; 
  list-style-type:none;
}
#menu { 
  margin-top: 100px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 10px; 
  left: 200px;
}
#menu a { 
  display: block; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: #3B5330;
}
#menu a:hover { background: #B0BD97;}
#menu ul li ul li a:hover { 
  background: #ECF1E7; 
  padding-left:9px;
  border-left: solid 1px #000;
}
#menu ul li ul li {
  width: 140px; 
  border: none; 
  color: #B0BD97;  
  padding-top: 3px; 
  padding-bottom:3px; 
  padding-left: 3px; 
  padding-right: 3px; 
  background: #B0BD97;
}
#menu ul li ul li a { 
  font: 11px arial; 
  font-weight:normal; 
  font-variant: small-caps; 
  padding-top:3px; 
  padding-bottom:3px;
}
#menu ul li {
  float: left; 
  width: 146px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  border-top: solid 1px #283923; 
  border-bottom: solid 1px #283923; 
  background: #979E71;
}
#menu ul li a { 
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}
#menu li {
  position:relative; 
  float:left;
}
#menu ul li ul, #menu:hover ul li ul, #menu:hover ul li:hover ul li ul {
  display:none;
  list-style-type:none;
  width: 140px;
}
#menu:hover ul, #menu:hover ul li:hover ul, #menu:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover ul {
  display:block;
}
#menu:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 145px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  font: 10px;
}
#menu:hover ul li:hover ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1px;
  font: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><center><a href="X">Home</a></center>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Disclaimer</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li> 
    <li>
      <center><a href="#">Practice Areas</a></center>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Civil Law</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Criminal Law &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &rsaquo;</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Joomla</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Drupal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
          </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Family Law &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &rsaquo;</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Joomla</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Drupal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
          </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Personal Injury &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&rsaquo;</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Joomla</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Drupal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
          </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Traffic Offenses &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&rsaquo;</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Joomla</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Drupal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
          </ul>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><center><a href="#">Attorney</a></center>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><center><a href="#">Contact Us</a></center>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Locations &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&rsaquo;</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Rockville Office</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Frederick Office</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Greenbelt Office</a></li>
          </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Phone Directory</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mailing Address</a></li>
      </ul>

    </li>

    <li><center><a href="#">Resources</a></center>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Helpful Links</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Affiliates &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&rsaquo;</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Healthcare Providers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Insurance Companies</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li></ul>
    <li><center><a href="#">News &amp; Events</a></center>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Press Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    <li><center><a href="#">Espanol</a></center>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
      </ul>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: could you also provide the HTML markup or a demo site?

Comment: Thanks for this question! just had one myself. Needed drop-up menu. And didn't find good tutorial on youtube.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Add `bottom:100%` to your `#menu:hover ul li:hover ul` rule

#### [Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/W5FWW/1/show/)

```
#menu:hover ul li:hover ul {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 1px;
    font: 10px;
    bottom: 100%; /* added this attribute */
}
```

---

Or better yet to prevent the submenus from having the same effect, just add this rule

#### [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/W5FWW/2/show)

```
#menu>ul>li:hover>ul { 
    bottom:100%;
}
```

---

#### [Demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/W5FWW/4/show)

source: http://jsfiddle.net/W5FWW/4/

And to get back the border you can add the following attribute

```
#menu>ul>li:hover>ul { 
    bottom:100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent
}
```

Comment: Oh you are awesome, thank you! But I have an additional nit-pick, when the menu flips up, the top border of the main menu bar vanishes (even when you start scrolling through the submenu), this doesn't happen then the menu flips down, any thoughts?

Comment: @Jenna added another demo and rule.  That should fix the border issue.

Comment: Thanks again, works perfectly! I'd give your answer a ^1 but I don't have enough points.

Comment: Would it be possible to animate this using css3?

Comment: @user1574041 Of course! just apply the appropriate transition atributes to whatever you need animated (e.g. `#menu a {transition:background-color 0.2s;}`). [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/W5FWW/582/)

Comment: @Joseph Marikle I see, i am trying to implement a certain css3 animation though. How would one make the ul with its submenu items slide upwards from the main menu item when hovering over the main link, instead of it just appearing. Is that possible with CSS3?

Comment: @user1574041 Yes it is indeed possible but it will take some work to implement.  Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/W5FWW/583/. Mine uses the css `bottom` attribute for its animation.  One major problem with it, however, is the fact that it hides the submenus behind the main nav.

Comment: i have similar problem but with option to resize container with appearing menu. reading - i dont want to cover my container with menu. any suggestions? i work with fixed, absolut and don't see any results ;/

Comment: this is brilliant. however is it possible to open the dropdown menu from top or bottom depending on the height area or location of the menu bar?

Answer (score 0):

If we are use chosen dropdown list, then we can use below css(No JS/JQuery require)

```
<select chosen="{width: '100%'}" ng- 
   model="modelName" class="form-control input- 
   sm"
   ng- 
   options="persons.persons as 
   persons.persons for persons in 
   jsonData"
   ng- 
   change="anyFunction(anyParam)" 
   required>
   <option value=""> </option>
</select>
<style>   
.chosen-container .chosen-drop {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 40px;
}

.chosen-container.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single {
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;

    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;

    background-image: none;
}

.chosen-container.chosen-with-drop .chosen-drop {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;

    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;

    box-shadow: none;

    margin-bottom: -16px;
}
</style>
```