# Dropdown Menu to open up when there isn't enough room on the screen - HTML/CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a drop-down that is in the middle of the document. When the drop-down shows up on the bottom of the screen, I want the drop-down to go up instead of down. When the drop-down shows up on the top of the screen, I want the drop-down to go down.

The drop-down is designed in HTML/CSS. I need the Javascript/jQuery code to make this work.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you! –

Comment: I would suggest posting what code you have into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that people can help you.

Comment: The HTML & CSS code can be found at the following location: http://jsfiddle.net/2h3Qw/

Answer (score 0):

First You have to find Top and Left coordinates of drop-down component. let coordibnates are x1,y1.
Then find width and height of screen via screenX and screenY.
then you can compare x1,y1 with screenX and screenY respectively.

you can do [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814186/drop-down-menu-that-opens-up-upward-with-pure-css)

Comment: The HTML & CSS code can be found at the following location: http://jsfiddle.net/2h3Qw/