# How to make nav submenus open above and below main bar, so no need to scroll

Tags: html, css, nav

I have a navigation bar created with html and css, it works well but I can't figure out how to get my sub menus to go above and below the bar when hovered, instead of all of them going below the bar, resulting in you having to scroll down the page.

Here is the html and css.

```
    <nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Five</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>




    <!-- language: lang-css -->

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul {
    background: #efefef; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    !border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    top:245px;
    display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}
    nav ul li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 32px;
    color: #757575;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
}

nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 40px;
    color: #fff;
}   
nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
}

nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: What's your html look like?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the html. I've added it now.

Comment: I suggest you to look [Drop-down menu that opens UP/upward with PURE CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814186/drop-down-menu-that-opens-up-upward-with-pure-css)

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I can't get that to work with my code.

Comment: Have you tried adding a negative top position on nav ul ul {} ?

Comment: hi if you add some image of what you want to achieve maybe it easy for me to understand and help you solve your problem.