# Drop-down menu that opens UP/upward CSS

Tags: nav

I'm fairly new to CSS so if someone can help me I'd be very appreciative!!!
I need to make a dropdown menu that drops up not down, since the nav bar is at the bottom of the page.

Here is the CSS for the nav bar

```
*   5.  Navigation                              *
************************************************/

#navigation {
    background: #000000;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #666666;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0px auto 1px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
    }

/*** ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/

.menu, .menu * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    }
.menu {
    line-height: 1.0;
    }
.menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
.menu ul ul, ul.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    width: 180px; /* left offset of submenus need to match (see below) */
    }
.menu ul li ul li, ul.menu ul li {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
.menu li:hover {
    visibility: inherit; /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
    }
.menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    }
.menu a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    }
.menu li:hover ul,
.menu li.sfHover ul {
    left: 0;
    top: 30px; /* match top ul list item height */
    z-index: 99;
    }
ul.menu li:hover li ul,
ul.menu li.sfHover li ul {
    top: -9999px;
    }
ul.menu li li:hover ul,
ul.menu li li.sfHover ul {
    left: 180px; /* match ul width */
    top: 0;
    }
ul.menu li li:hover li ul,
ul.menu li li.sfHover li ul {
    top: -9999px;
    }

ul.menu li li li:hover ul,
ul.menu li li li.sfHover ul {
    left: 180px; /* match ul width */
    top: 0;
    }

/*** SKIN ***/

#navigation .menu .current_page_item a,
#navigation .menu .current_page_ancestor a,
#navigation .menu .current-menu-item a,
#navigation .menu .current-cat a {
    background: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    }
#navigation .menu li .current_page_item a, #navigation .menu li .current_page_item a:hover,
#navigation .menu li .current-menu-item a, #navigation .menu li .current-menu-item a:hover,
#navigation .menu li .current-cat a, #navigation .menu li .current-cat a:hover {
    background: #242424;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    }
#navigation .menu .current_page_item ul li a,
#navigation .menu .current-menu-item ul li a,
#navigation .menu .current-menu-ancestor ul li a,
#navigation .menu .current_page_ancestor ul li a,
#navigation .menu .current-cat ul li a {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #333333;
    }
#navigation .menu .current_page_item ul li a:hover,
#navigation .menu .current-menu-item ul li a:hover,
#navigation .menu .current-menu-ancestor ul li a:hover,
#navigation .menu .current_page_ancestor ul li a:hover,
#navigation .menu .current-menu-ancestor ul .current_page_item a,
#navigation .menu .current_page_ancestor ul .current-menu-item a,
#navigation .menu .current-cat ul li a:hover {
    background: #F2F2F2;
    color: #000000;
    }
#navigation .menu .current_page_item .sub-menu a,
#navigation .menu .current_page_ancestor .sub-menu a,
#navigation .menu .current-menu-item .sub-menu a,
#navigation .menu .current-cat .sub-menu a {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #333333;
    }
#navigation .menu .current_page_item .sub-menu a:hover,
#navigation .menu .current_page_ancestor .sub-menu a:hover,
#navigation .menu .current-menu-item .sub-menu a:hover,
#navigation .menu .current-cat .sub-menu a:hover {
    background: #F2F2F2;
    color: #000000;
    }
.menu {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    }
.menu a {
    background: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    }
.menu a, .menu a:link, .menu a:visited  { /* visited pseudo selector so IE6 applies text colour*/
    color: #999999;
    }
.menu a:focus, .menu a:hover, .menu a:active {
    background: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    outline: 0;
    }
.menu li li a, .menu li li a:link, .menu li li a:visited {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #666666;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    }
.menu li li a:focus, .menu li li a:hover, .menu li li a:active {
    background: #F2F2F2;
    color: #333333;
    border-bottom: none;
    outline: 0;
    }
.menu li.sfHover a {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #333333;
    }
.menu li {
    margin: 0px;
    }
.menu li li {
    border: none;
    }
.menu li:hover, .menu li.sfHover {
    background: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    outline: 0;
    }
.menu li li:hover, .menu li li.sfHover {
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    }

/*** ARROWS **/

.menu a.sf-with-ul {
    padding-right: 25px;
    min-width: 1px; /* trigger IE7 hasLayout so spans position accurately */
    }
.sf-sub-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 10px;
    top: 9px; /* IE6 only */
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(images/arrows-ffffff.png) no-repeat -10px -100px; /* 8-bit indexed alpha png. IE6 gets solid image only */
    }
a > .sf-sub-indicator {  /* give all except IE6 the correct values */
    top: 9px;
    background-position: 0 -100px; /* use translucent arrow for modern browsers*/
    }
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator,
a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator,
a:active > .sf-sub-indicator,
li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator,
li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
    background-position: -10px -100px; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
    }
/* point right for anchors in subs */
.menu ul ul .sf-sub-indicator, ul.menu ul .sf-sub-indicator { 
    background-position:  -10px 0; 
    }
.menu ul ul a > .sf-sub-indicator, ul.menu ul a > .sf-sub-indicator { 
    top: 8px;
    background-position:  0 0; 
    }
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
.menu ul ul a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator,
.menu ul ul a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator,
.menu ul ul a:active > .sf-sub-indicator,
.menu ul ul li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator,
.menu ul ul li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
    background-position: -10px 0; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
    }
/*** shadows for all but IE6 ***/
.sf-shadow ul ul {
    background: none;
    padding: 0 8px 9px 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 17px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 17px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 17px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 17px;
    }
.sf-shadow ul.sf-shadow-off {
    background: transparent;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814186/drop-down-menu-that-opens-up-upward-with-pure-css) is a post with 3 demos of upward expanding drop-downs. They've even added a jsFiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

can you maybe provide a link to the live code so i can see exactly how its set up, or you can add the html in to your question too, then i'll be happy to help you.
meanwhile if you just whant a simple example here is one: [Link to Drop up](http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/dropup3.htm)