# css make drop down list open to up (opposite direction) and not to down

Tags: css

I have created a dropdown list using css. The drop down list works perfect, opening the menu to down. How can I modified in order to open the menu to up (opposite direction)? make something like drop up list.
This is my html code.

```
<div id="menu">

<ul>
   <li><a href="#"> <?php   echo $user_data['name']; ?> </a>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
          <li><a href="changepassword.php">Change Password</a><li>
          <li><a href="settings.php">Settings</a><li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#"> Profile </a>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="profile_menu.php">Edit Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php  echo $user_data['email'];  ?>">View Profile</a></li>  
       </ul>
   </li>
        <li><a href="wall.php"> Home </a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

and this is my css.

```
#menu ul{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
list-style:none;
}

#menu ul li {
    float:left;
}

#menu ul li a:hover{
background:#fff;
color:#333;
}


#menu ul li ul{
position:absolute;
height:0px;
overflow:hidden;
}

#menu ul li ul li{
float:none;
}


#menu ul li:hover ul{
overflow:visible;
}


#menu ul li:hover ul li a{
padding:10px;
}


#menu ul li ul li a{
-webkit-transition:0.3s;
-moz-transition:0.3s;
padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this may help you.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814186/drop-down-menu-that-opens-up-upward-with-pure-css

Comment: I have added bottom:300px; to #menu ul li:hover ul,  the menu goes up but not allow me to select

Comment: ok needs to be bottom:180px; but still not working good, any other ideas?

Comment: My suggestion would be to study the code provided thoroughly.  If you don't understand one part or section of code, post a new question about it. The answer is there.

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/bjornmeansbear/pen/MwGYZL

The following CSS should help you — it incorporates the "drop-up" and also cleans up a few other things...

```
#menu {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#menu ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#menu a { display: block;}

#menu a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
}

#menu ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 250%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul {
  height: initial;
  bottom: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  background: lightgray;
}

#menu li li a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

#menu a {
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

Basically, if you position the `<li>` that houses the child `<ul>` relatively, you can use the absolute position of the `<ul>` to position it anywhere based directly on its the parent... does that make sense?