# Dropdown Menu as Selectbox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was trying to style a select but gave up for incompatibility issues with IE8 and Safari. 
So I thought to use a dropdown instead of the select and then another problem appeared. 
When a select is near the bottom of a page, the options appear above the select rather than the bottom, which is the default. 
What I want to know is if anyone has a solution using jQuery to make the dropdown options appear above it as the select options

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Dropdown Menu</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            * {border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

            div {
                background-color: #09C;
                width: 200px;
                line-height: 40px;
                bottom: 40px;
                left: 300px;
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                text-indent: 15px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            div span {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 16px;
                color: #FFF;
            }

            div:hover ul {display: block;}

            div ul {
                background-color: #0f0;
                width: 200px;
                height: 300px;
                position: absolute;
                display: none;
                list-style: none;
            }

            div ul li {
                background-color: #000;
                width: 200px;
                line-height: 30px;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 16px;
                color: #FFF;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span>Dropdown</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Link 01</li>
                <li>Link 02</li>
                <li>Link 03</li>
                <li>Link 04</li>
                <li>Link 05</li>
                <li>Link 06</li>
                <li>Link 07</li>
                <li>Link 08</li>
                <li>Link 09</li>
                <li>Link 10</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: You can use selectmenu jquery plugin here.

Comment: @jp310 try this http://jsfiddle.net/tL5jn/

Comment: so you want the options above right, by default they are below...

Comment: updaed fiddle:http:http://jsfiddle.net/t9cax/1/

Comment: @jp310 your solution requires the top: value to be manually given depending on number of list elements, so i made the list order to reverse using margins.
You can refer to my answer to see exactly what it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="dropdown"> <span>Dropdown</span>

    <ul>
        <li>Link 01</li>
        <li>Link 02</li>
        <li>Link 03</li>
        <li>Link 04</li>
        <li>Link 05</li>
        <li>Link 06</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div {
    background-color: #09C;
    line-height: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    left: 300px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-indent: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div span {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFF;
}
div:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
div ul {
    background-color: #0f0;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
}
div ul li {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ul_h = $('ul').height();
    var dd_h = $('#dropdown').height();
    var doc_h = $(document).height();
    var offsetTop = $('#dropdown').offset().top;
    if (doc_h - offsetTop - dd_h < ul_h) {
        $('#dropdown ul').css('bottom', '100%');
    }
});
```

This jQuery will calculate current position of div and height of menu, and if space between div and bottom of the page is smaller than dropdown height, then dropdown will show up above.

Here is demo with dropdown above (`div {bottom: 40px;}`)
http://jsfiddle.net/wxA2u/

and here is demo with dropdown below (`div {top: 40px;}`)
http://jsfiddle.net/wxA2u/1/

Comment: @MiljanPuzovićPerfect, exactly what I wanted. I am immensely grateful for your help. My special thanks to you and also to all who responded.

Comment: @Learning, you're welcome. If this is right answer, please accept it (green check sign). You can vote up, also :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a **pure CSS solution**. In your current rule add the rule 'bottom: 100%;'. (see below)

```
div ul {
  background-color: #0f0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  bottom: 100%; /* <- add this */
}
```

Cool, right?

This is a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814186/drop-down-menu-that-opens-up-upward-with-pure-css).

Comment: @pizzasynthesis-Pure CSS is also good, but in this particular case does not solve my problem, unfortunately, but thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/avi_sagi/5dzme/1/

Extra CSS:

```
div ul{
margin-top:-10px;
}
div ul li{
margin-top:-60px;
}
```

See what this does is it pulls each list item up by double its height so in turn reversing the order from top-bottom to bottom-top
so u get what u want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sagi_Avinash_Varma-I had not thought of this solution, simple and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have updated the top value based on the current window size.. Please check this [**`Fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/tL5jn/11/)... this might helps you..

**Script:**

```
function calculateTop(element, popup) {
    var height = element.outerHeight(), 
    popupHeight = popup.height(),
    pos = element.offset(),
    top = pos.top, bottom = $(window).height() - (top + height);

    if (bottom > popupHeight || top < popupHeight)
        return height;
    else
        return -popupHeight;
}
```

Here is the script i have used to calculate the top value..

Comment: @SoundarRThank you, as I'm learning, your script will be very useful in my studies.