# Add an "click outside of menu to close" jQuery / Javascript to a menu drop-up that has .toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I would like to add the function to close the menu if I click outside the menu.

And also keep the menu button working to close it too: https://jsfiddle.net/ezkay/1he5bhzt/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").toggle()).hide();
    });
});
```

Also can you tell me if this is correct for mobile etc? I hope and think so, because it's using .click, right?

This is referring to this post, that I can't reply to the answer to ask there:
[How to change drop-down menu to drop-up menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043151/how-to-change-drop-down-menu-to-drop-up-menu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1he5bhzt/2/)**

The following does the trick.

```
$(document).on('click',function (e) {
  footerUl = $('ul:first li');
  if (!footerUl.is(e.target) 
      && footerUl.has(e.target).length === 0){
    footerUl.children('ul').hide();
  }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("li").click(function () {
    $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").toggle()).hide();
  });
});

$(document).on('click',function (e) {
  footerUl = $('ul:first li');
  if (!footerUl.is(e.target) 
      && footerUl.has(e.target).length === 0){
    footerUl.children('ul').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
div {
    background: #999999;
    height: 40px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #000000;
    margin: -8px;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
}
ul, li, a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}
ul > li {
    float: right;
}
ul > li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 40px;
    height:40px;
    display:block;
    padding:0px 10px;
}
ul li a:hover {
    background: #666666;
}
ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: #333333;
    bottom:40px;
    width: 200px;
    right: 0px;
}
ul li ul li {
    float: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">=</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">one</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">two</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">three</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! Would hit you up with 100 points if i could ;D

Answer (score 0):

I would attach click event to the document and then check for child elements.
Assuming your LI element has class "menu":

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("menu")) {
        //close menu here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! But I'm don't understand how to get this working -.- Probably I have to give classes to all the ul and li. But witch one needs `.menu?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to close when somebody clicks outside the ul tag. You need to capture all click events in the document. And then check if the click happened outside the ul tag. If it was outside then close the menu

```
var myelement = $('ul')
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var el = e.target();
    if(!$.contains(myelement, el)) { //checks if the click happened outside the ul tag
        //close menu
    }
})
```

Comment: Basically you need to capture all the clicks in the document. Check if the click was within Doms in your menu. If not then it is a click outside the menu.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it difficult for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!