# Is it possible to open dropdown menu from lower to upper side?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am using 
[DDSLICK](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) for displaying a customized dropdown my website , now Problem is I have disabled overflow on my page because of which my dropdown is not visible fully Please see attached image [image]
Now as a solution for this problem is it possible to open dropdown from lower to upper side?

Comment: We cannot help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814186/drop-down-menu-that-opens-up-upward-with-pure-css

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. place the combo box on the bottom of a new canvas.. make the size of the canvas as fixed. when u click it to drop down , it will not have space to drop down and will be forced to "drop up".. just Check it out..