# How select/option open in top?

Tags: html, css

How to open the SELECT / Open to the top. By default the list is always opened down, how to change it? If the standard methods of html / css

```
  <select>
    <option>Пункт 1</option>
    <option>Пункт 2</option>
  </select>
```

It is desirable standard features

Comment: maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814186/drop-down-menu-that-opens-up-upward-with-pure-css

Comment: A echli use the standard list (ul / li) set his max-height, and if the height is less than for the input unit to display the list from top to bottom?

Comment: Thanks dllhell decision to resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, It's not possible with native select list. You have to implement a customised select list.

Comment: A echli use the standard list (ul / li) set his max-height, and if the height is less than for the input unit to display the list from top to bottom?