# Change Drop down direction to upwards

Tags: codeigniter, drop-down-menu, codeigniter-3, dropdown, direction

I have created a drop down with the functions of codeigniter and I want to change it's direction to upwards. any idea ?

```
  <div class="col-lg-8 validate-parent">
    <?php echo form_dropdown('approved_by" id="approved_by" required class="form-control text-left chosen-select"', $employee); ?>
 </div>
```

[image]

I have tried with css but no result

Comment: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/155

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop-down menu that opens up/upward with pure css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814186/drop-down-menu-that-opens-up-upward-with-pure-css)