# navbar is not opening correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed bottom navbar, my "links" list does not open on hover. when I can get it to open it opens down and not upwards. I did add `bottom: 0;` to the hover section in CSS and that didn't work.. any help would be appreciated 
-new to HTML and CSS, this will be for a school final project!

added `bottom: 0;` to the hover section in CSS
tried commenting out sections to fix
played around with margin/padding
and tried a z function thing

link to the code
https://codepen.io/wickedmango/pen/rNBQPNG

looking to have the "links list" open upwards, and to be in front of everything!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814186/drop-down-menu-that-opens-up-upward-with-pure-css Check out this one.

Comment: Please include a [mre] in the question itself, not only on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove

> overflow: hidden

from **nav** class

Add

```
nav ul li:hover ul {
  bottom: 60px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! this worked and was exactly what i needed!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes the issue was overflow hidden but you want to give the nav a z-index greater than anything so it can be in front of anything:

```
nav {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-color: white;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 100;
```

}

https://codepen.io/izzy_zeke/pen/bGbQzLg

Also if I may I would like to give you an advice and use css flex rather than doing something like floats to help you with better standards:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: thanks for the extra tip! much appreciated and ill take the time to look it over!