# How to force menu to open upwards in a searchable dropdown?

Tags: html, css

I have an html code below

Dropdown-->
  
    
    About
    Base
    Blog
    Contact
    Custom
    Support
    Tools

Its basically taken from this website https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_filter

This is how it looks like

[image]

It does a search on the items displayed in the menu. Now I want this menu to open upwards and not downwards

On looking online, I found I have to provide `bottom: 100%;` [Drop-down menu that opens up/upward with pure css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814186/drop-down-menu-that-opens-up-upward-with-pure-css). Now in my case, there are no `<ul>` or `<li>` tags. So this is what I did

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 100%; //added this
}
```

But it doesn't do anything. How can I force the menu to show upwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```
.dropdown-content.show {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    bottom: 45px; /* hardcoded height of the button */
}
```

Using w3cschool's existing code:

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  var dropdown, button;
  dropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  button = document.getElementById("myButton");
  dropdown.classList.toggle("show");
  dropdown.style.bottom = button.offsetHeight + "px";
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {
  outline: 3px solid #ddd;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 250px; /* just for demo purposes */
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
  flex-direction: column-reverse; /* show children in a reversed colum (bottom to top) */
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<h2>Search/Filter Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu, and use the input field to search for a specific dropdown link.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="myButton" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

I just removed the hardcoded button height from the CSS and instead calculated the height using Javascript.
See the modified function `myFunction()` and the added `id="myButton"` in the markup.

Comment: @SouvikRay Happy to help! I just edited the code a bit removing the hardcoded button height and instead calculating it with JavaScript, making it more flexible.

Comment: hey buddy! need your help again. The fix you mentioned worked great but somehow scroll doesn't work. I added this property to my `.dropdown-content` `overflow-y: auto;`
  `height: 200px;` and this worked with regular dropdown but after the change to show menu upwards, this has stopped working. Any idea why?

Comment: `max-height: 200px;` does the trick, at least in Chrome.
Anyways, that'a a separate question. Try to find answers about overflow with flexbox or post it as a separate question ;)